# How to prevent empty input on a WinSock in C

Tags: c, winsock

I have a WinSock client script in C that, when i just press enter without any input, hangs up. sry i cant tell you more, i tried to read the buffer after the input but not even this is working. Thats my code:

```
    printf("\ninput [max 256]: ");
    gets(buf);
    send(s,buf,strlen(buf),0);
    rc=recv(s,buf,256,0);
    if(rc==0)
    {
      printf("Server hat die Verbindung getrennt..\n");
      break; // also tried without
    }
    if(rc==SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
      printf("Fehler: recv, fehler code: %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
      break; // also tried without
    }
    buf[rc]='\0';
    printf("output: %s\n",buf);
```

Comment: Do you receive anything? What is the value of `rc`? What is the contents of the received buffer? *How* is it not working? Is there anything being sent? What is being sent?

Comment: on server side i receive nothing and the client buffer i cant read as i said. i have no opinion except `^c`

Comment: And what do you mean by "can't read"? Do the `recv` call never return? Are both the server and client both waiting on `recv`? Does `send` return with a failure?

Comment: it hangs up, it quits, the script wont work even more after that..

Comment: Then maybe you have a crash? Have you tried running in a debugger? What is `buf`? How is it initialized?

Comment: i got it, the client just blocks because it was waiting endless for the echo. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you do not tell us anything about the server side we may only guess:

1. `gets(buf)` and "just pressing enter" leaves `buf` "empty".
2. `send(s,buf,strlen(buf),0);` sends nothing, as `buf` had been left "empty".
3. Assuming an echo-server it "echos" (sends) nothing, as nothing had been received by it, send to it from the client.
4. `rc=recv(s,buf,256,0);` waits forever as nothing had been send ("echoed") by the server.

To get around the blocking in step 4 you might consider

- using a non-blocking socket to read from the server.

  Doing so would let `recv()` fail immediately if nothing is available from the server.
- calling `select()` to test if the socket is ready for reading.

  You can set a timeout to keep `select()` from blocking.

---

Note:

- Do not use `gets()` as it is unsecure by allowing the user to overflow the buffer passed. `gets()` is not part of Standard C anymore.
- There are no C-scripts. What you show is C-code.

Comment: hmm ok thank you. sry i cant tell you more because i dont know what should i do.. 3) doesnt the server just echoes when there came in something to echo? how can i try this? nr 4 sounds "good" in my case but how can i check this? and also how can i prevent it please? i will add some server code.